# Cluster Management using JMX

Tags: java, cluster-computing, jmx

I am currently an IT trainee and have a new issue to figure out, dealing with JMX.

My company is using JManage because it contains an application cluster support, so that they can perform operations accross their  Tomcat clusters. However, Jmanage is not maintained anymore, and they got dead nodes without knowing the reason.

As some non Java users are also working with JManage, my mission is to find a JMX console web application which have a cluster support.

I searched on the Internet and couldn't find something equivalent as JManage does. I found a lot of JConsole like JMinix, MC4J but it's not what my company expected. I didn't find documentation about Jolokia and clustering.
As I want to make sure that any software already exits, I prefer ask everyone if you know a web app that I can use to replace JManage?

If it is not the case, I have to try building a new software doing this. It will be my first software to develop, do you have any advice about how I can do it? Starting from JManage open source code and investigate what doesn't work? It will be helpful to have other points of views before starting! :)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Search for JMX Cascading/OpenDMK. There is a [mavenized github repo](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK) of OpenDMK that will bridge together multiple mbean servers.